# Why declare field widget before super init?

Tags: django

I am a noob at Python and Django and attempting to learn it as I go along, however, there is one thing that confuses me.

In a custom field of mine I have:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = None
    self.widget = ReCaptcha
    super(ReCaptchaField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.required = True
    self.error_messages = {'required': self.default_error_messages['captcha_invalid']}
```

and I cannot seem to understand why declaring the field widget works where it is but not after:

```
super(ReCaptchaField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Instead it actually produces an error whereby:

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
```

In my widget actually is not passed `self` for some reason.

However:

```
self.error_messages = {'required': self.default_error_messages['captcha_invalid']}
```

only works after calling the `super`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently have no way to confirm this, but I would provide a possible way to explain this.

It's clearer to check the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/forms/fields/#Field) for answer here. `self.widget` is expecting a class and widget will later be initialized as a class instance in `__init__` in parent class:

```
widget = widget or self.widget
if isinstance(widget, type):
    widget = widget()    # the instance initialization
```

If you do the assignment after `super`, your widget remains a class and will never be initialized, thus it is not going to work.

On the other hand, `error_messages` is actually an optional parameter for `__init__` method. If you provide that in `__init__` function, it will take it to the `self.error_messages`. Otherwise, it's empty dict:

```
messages = {}
for c in reversed(self.__class__.__mro__):
    messages.update(getattr(c, 'default_error_messages', {}))
# see here. Did you provide any error_messages? If no then {}
messages.update(error_messages or {})
# self.error_messages might be {} because the above code
self.error_messages = messages
```

So if you do `self.error_messsages` before the `super`, it will be overridden with `{}`.